# Cookie Manager of Apache JMeter doesn't add the cookie to POST request

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I build up very simple test plan.

1. Login: POST, a session cookie is returned.
2. Get the state: GET, a user state is returned.
3. Create a resource: POST, JSON body is supplied for the resource.

So my 'Test Plan' looks like:

- Test Plan

  - Thread Group

    - HTTP Request Defaults
    - HTTP Cookie Manager
    - Login (HTTP Request Sampler: POST)
    - Get State (HTTP Request Sampler: GET)
    - Create Resource (HTTP Request Sampler: POST)

The cookie generated by 'Login' is added to 'Get State' correctly.
But 'Create Resource' has NO cookie. I changed their order but it doesn't help.
I used the default options firstly and changed some options but it also doesn't help.

Is it a bug of JMeter? or just POST http request is not able to have cookie? 
Please give me any advice.

**[SOLVED]**
I noticed that it is related to the path, not the method.
You'd like to look at the domain of the cookie as well as the path.
I mean, the path and the domain of a cookie could be defined in the server side through Set-Cookie header.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with your solution. This helped me.

Comment: Hi , can u please explain..the steps how u did this..?

Comment: Just in case anyone else faces the same issue, enabling follow redirects solved the cookie issue for me

Comment: I am also facing similar issue related to path. cookie is set to particular path on the domain, lets say "/admin", but when i hit/send the request to that path, only cookie set to the root domain, i.e., "/" is send. But we need to send both the cookies of "/" and "/admin" paths. how can solve this issue? I am using JMeter 3.1

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to set CookieManager.check.cookies=false in jmeter.properties usually sitting besides the jmeter startup script in bin.

JMeter for some reasons thinks that you can't set the path=/something in a cookie if you are on http:/somesite/somethingelse. That is the path has to match the path your currently on.

I've never seen a browser enforce this limitation if it actually exists. I've seen and written several sites that use this technique to set a secure cookie and then forward someone say to /admin.

I wish this option was at least in the GUI so I didn't have to change the properties file. I think BlazeMeter is smart enough to turn off checking where flood.io is not. If it were up to me I'd just remove the code that checks this entirely. Why make the load tester any harder then it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I had this turned on in my Spring Boot server which was causing the issue with CookieManager in jMeter:

server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true

Removing this made the cookies flow ! Of course this is for localhost. For Production you may need this turned on.