# jmeter - second post request is not using the JSESSIONID created on my log in post request

Tags: post, https, jmeter, jsessionid

I was successfully able to send a POST request for my log in end point and a JSESSIONID was created.  I know the JSESSIONID is kept by the HTTP Cookie Manager that I have at the top of my thread because I see it being used on several GET requests I have in my thread.

But when I attempt a POST request it does not use the JSESSIONID and creates its own ID. Below are my settings:

Protocol: https
Method: POST
-Use KeppAlive
{"json":"params"}

**Sampler Result:**
Thread Name: sim test 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-02-18 15:42:42 EST
Load time: 95
Latency: 95
Size in bytes: 239
Headers size in bytes: 239
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 302
Response message: Found

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F16BF82FD28A84F6E28DDE30DECDC48C; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: https : //api.zzzz com/site/needsAuth
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 20:42:42 GMT

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

**Request:**
POST https : //api.zzz com/rest/members/347/passengers

POST data:
{"relationshipToMember":null,"authorizedToBook":false,"authorizedToFly":true,"authorizedToGetInfo":false,"passenger":{"firstName":"Mighty","middleName":null,"lastName":"Max","dateOfBirth": 1380857200000}}

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 204
Host: api.zzz.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)

-Note: I don't know if I am doing my GET requests correctly but they are working. They have Follow Redirects on and it first goes to http : //api.zzz... - 302 Found, then goes https : //api.zzz...

edit:
I found this which is exactly my problem: [Cookie Manager of Apache JMeter doesn't add the cookie to POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966576/cookie-manager-of-apache-jmeter-doesnt-add-the-cookie-to-post-request), but I do not understand his solution if anyone can elaborate on the steps.

**UPDATE**
Solved: I had to keep the same Server Name as my Log in POST and change my Path

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE!!!**

Haven't noticed your **https** protocol.

All you need is to set either `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` property in your `jmeter.properties` file or add it as an argument to JMeter command line as

```
jmeter -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true -n -t path_to_jmx_script.jmx -l path_to_log_file.jtl
```

Leaving the rest of my response just in case anyone else will need it as a guide on how to share JMeter Cookies across different Thread Groups.

I'm not able to reproduce your use case in my environment using following scenarios:

- HTTP Cookie Manager lives under Test Plan (same level as Thread Group(s))
- HTTP Cookie Manager lives under Thread Group (same level as Samplers)

It's only reproducible if HTTP Cookie Manager added as a child of Login request. If it's your case - move it up 1 level to broaden it's scope.

If for some reason it doesn't help - see below for possible workaround details.

Your response code `204` doesn't sound like an error to me. I guess that the server would rather respond with something like `401` or `403` if there were problems with cookie-based authentication.

If you explicitly need to set cookie it still can be done via i.e. Beanshell

You need to do the following:

1. If you're going to share cookies between different thread groups or need them as JMeter variables for any other reason set `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` property either in `jmeter.properties` file or specify it during JMeter startup as `jmeter -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true`
2. Add Beanshell Post Processor to your Login Request with following code:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

   CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();

   props.put("cookiecount", String.valueOf(manager.getCookieCount()));

   for (int i = 0; i < manager.getCookieCount(); i++) {
       props.put("cookie_name" + i, manager.get(i).getName());
       props.put("cookie_value" + i, manager.get(i).getValue());
       props.put("cookie_domain" + i, manager.get(i).getDomain());
       props.put("cookie_path" + i, manager.get(i).getPath());
       props.put("cookie_expires" + i, String.valueOf(manager.get(i).getExpires()));
       props.put("cookie_secure" + i, String.valueOf(manager.get(i).getSecure()));
   }
   ```
3. Add Beanshell Pre Processor to your `POST` request with following code:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.JMeterProperty;


   CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();

   int count = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("cookiecount"));

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       Cookie cookie = new Cookie(props.getProperty("cookie_name" + i), props.getProperty("cookie_value" + i),
               props.getProperty("cookie_domain" + i), props.getProperty("cookie_path" + i),
               Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty("cookie_secure" + i)),
               Long.parseLong(props.getProperty("cookie_expires" + i)));
       manager.add(cookie);
   }

   JMeterProperty cookieprop = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager");

   cookieprop.setObjectValue(manager);

   ctx.getCurrentSampler().setProperty(cookieprop);
   ```

Explanation:

The code at point 2 fetches all available cookies from [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and stores them to JMeter Properties prefixed with `cookie_`

The code at point 3 reads all properties prefixed with `cookie_`, constructs JMeter Cookies from them and adds them to HTTP Cookie Manager.

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on extending JMeter via scripting.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I tried your above direction and my second POST request(after the log-in POST request) is still creating it's own jsessionID. The Request result still says "[no cookies]". My cookie manager is at the thread level btw. Is there any more info I can give you that may help?

Comment: To confirm, If I have Redirect Automatically or Follow Redirects on it tried to turn my request into a GET request. So I have neither of these checked. Is this the correct way to go?

Comment: To turn your request to GET request you need to change "Method". You could try posting an image of your Test Plan here to give us a clue, however the behavior looks weird. Are you sure that it is the same thread doing login followed by post?

Comment: I want it to remain as POST request, which is why I uncheck Redirect Auto and Follow Redirect. Is the correct thing to do? I can't post images bc I don't have enough rep points. But here are some links. In that run I took https out.

http://grab.by/utL4
http://grab.by/utLa
http://grab.by/utLg
http://grab.by/utLk
http://grab.by/utLq

Answer (score 0):

I had to keep the same Server Name/IP as my Log in POST and change my Path