# JMeter shows cookie data variable set twice

Tags: apache, variables, cookies, jmeter

This is my first time working with Apache JMeter so bear with me.  I have created a test that goes to my site, logs into the site, sets one user type, logs out of the site, logs back into the site, and sets a different user type.

Setting the first user type goes swell: 
[image: Test setup]

[image: Request]

The next step shows that the data was set successfully: 
[image: Next Step]

However, the step after this shows that the variable is set a second time, which causes issues for me later on. 
[image: variable twice]

I have no clue why it would be setting it again. The cookie manager does not seem to have any hints: 
[image: Cookie Manager]

Any ideas?

Comment: works as designed: until that cookie is removed or set to a different value, it will be sent with every request. Note that iteration refers to thread iteration, not iteration of the loop controller.

Comment: @KirilS. But why is it setting two of the same value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "setting two of the same value". In the screenshots what you highlighted I see 2 requests, both having cookies sent with the request. And as I said, they will be sent with every request as long as they exist. They are not `set-cookie` received from the server, if this is the confusion.

Comment: @KirilS. Look at the second to last screenshot. `active_user_type_session_key=PROCESSOR` is listed twice, when it's not in the previous screenshot

Comment: oh, I see. Well, it means only one thing: the previous request did send the cookie (with `set-cookie` header), so JMeter now has 2 of them (they probably either have a different path or domain). You can check that by saving cookies in properties, see answer here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865414/jmeter-second-post-request-is-not-using-the-jsessionid-created-on-my-log-in-po. BeanSHell can also help you to delete unwanted cookie.

Comment: @KirilS. is there a way to see what the path or domain of the cookies is?

Comment: Yes, the page I mentioned above, has a code for doing so (look for code under "Add Beanshell Post Processor to your Login Request with following code")

Comment: @KirilS. trying it out. I'm pretty new to this, so I'm not sure where I view what `props.put` is outputting?

Comment: You can replace `props.put` with `System.out.println` and see it in the log

Comment: @KirilS. you were right! One has `/test/` as a path, while the other has `/test` as a path.  What would cause that?

Comment: @KirilS. you were absolutely correct, the reason it was using two domains was because I have a default path set to `/test`, and later on in the HTTP Request was using `/test//direct.php`.  Took out the extra slash and it works.  Feel free to write an answer, that I'll mark as accepted if you want the rep